# Two VGA monitors on Lenovo IdeaCentre H520 Desktop

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, vga

I recently bought a Lenovo IdeaCentre H520 computer and two VGA LED monitors. This particular PC has a dedicated NVIDIA Geforce GT630 video card and an integrated Intel HD Graphics 2500 video card. Both cards have VGA out. The Geforce card also has a HDMI out.

I have installed Windows 8 and I can't seem to use both cards. I have connected both monitors, one to the VGA out of the Geforce card and one to the VGA out of the integrated card. I looked through the BIOS options for Video and I can only select the dedicated one, the integrate one or the Auto option.

This kinda sucks. I was wondering what kind of options I have available.

I have a VGA female to DVI A male adaptor, I was wondering if it could work if I can hook it to a DVI A female to HDMI male adaptor and plug one monitor into the VGA out of the Geforce video card and the other through both adapters to the HDMI out. Any chance this could work? I was looking online for a VGA to HDMI live cable but it's kind of expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when you install a discrete graphics card (your Geforce) the on-board graphics is disabled. In some instances they can both be used if the BIOS supports it, but you should have found that option in the BIOS settings.

You should definitely be able to use both outputs on the Geforce card to run both monitors, however.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regarding my second question, can I, in theory, use two linked adapters to go through VGA - DVI A - HDMI ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not believe that will work. The HDMI cable only transmits digital signal, while the VGA port on your TV is analog. You'd need an expensive digital>analog converter.

Comment: Here's one: http://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Active-Female-Adapter/dp/B00879DM56/  I guess they're not too expensive.